# Convert COUNTIFS for use in XL2003

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 formula's that work fine in XL2010, but not in XL2003, I figured out that COUNTIFS are the problem. 
Could someone help me convert them so I can use them in both versions of XL

This is one of the XL2010 codes:

> =COUNTIFS(CXPATS!I:I,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-4)+1,CXPATS!I:I,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)

Below is one of my many attempts using SUMPRODUCT, but they either don't work or continually show #NUM!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CXPATS!I:I>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-4)+1,--(CXPATS!I:I<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1))
```

This is the other XL2010 code:

> {=SUM(COUNTIFS(CXPATS!L:L,{"6859*","685A*"}))}

...and one of my many attempts using SUMPRODUCT again, but again I keep getting #NUM! on most attempts

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CXPATS!L:L="6859*"),--(CXPATS!L:L="685A*"))
```

Comment: `SUM(COUNT(IF('    ', TRUE, FALSE)))`pattern as array formula may work for you in `Excel 2003`. Can you put some sample data and expected output so that we can test and give you correct formula.

Comment: The 1st formula just looks at one column of dates and counts how many are next month. The 2nd is just a list of codes in one column from 685 to 685ZZ and counts how many are 6859* and 685A*

Comment: I think your "=SUMPRODUCT(--(CXPATS!I:I>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-4)+1,--(CXPATS!I:I<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1))" is missing an end bracket, probably after the first "+1".

Comment: I have figured out the 2nd now by adding 2 COUNTIF together =COUNTIF(CXPATS!L:L,"6859*")+(COUNTIF(CXPATS!L:L,"685A*"))

Comment: I tried adding the other bracket but it's still the same #NUM! result: =SUMPRODUCT(--(CXPATS!I:I>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-4)+1),--(CXPATS!I:I<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1))

Comment: The problem was not restricting the range. As soon as I changed from I:I to I2:I4000 it worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference whole columns using SUMPRODUCT so I used a DNR instead (shown below as DATES in the code) to get the exact range and the formula now works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATES>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-4)+1),--(DATES<EOMONTH(TODAY(),‌​-1)+1))
```